# cin is eating output stream

Tags: c++, cout, cin

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int conversion, hash;

    cout << "Select one." << endl;
    cout << "0: Radix Method 32" << endl;
    cout << "1: Radix Method 64" << endl;
    cout << "2: SumUp" << endl;
    cin >> conversion;

    cout << endl << "Select one." << endl;
    cout << "0: Division" << endl;
    cout << "1: Multiplication" << endl;
    cin >> hash;

    cout << "Conversion: " + conversion << endl;
    cout << "hash: " + hash << endl;
}
```

As simple as this is, I'm getting wild output.  I feel like it's something obvious but I'm too tired to see it.  The number I enter into the variables is the number of characters removed from the next output string.  ex:

```
Select one.
0: Radix Method 32
1: Radix Method 64
2: SumUp
1

Select one.
0: Division
1: Multiplication
2
onversion:
sh:
Press any key to continue . . .

Select one.
0: Radix Method 32
1: Radix Method 64
2: SumUp
5

Select one.
0: Division
1: Multiplication
1
rsion:
ash:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Am I crazy or does this make no sense? Am I using `cin` wrong?  I haven't used C++ for a few months, but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: `void main(int argc, char* argv[])` in global scope is invalid in C++. Change its type of return value to `int`.

Comment: "Conversion" + conversion?!

Comment: You are not crazy and it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

`cout << "Conversion: " + conversion` means to print from `conversion` elements after the head of the array.

You may want this (change `+` to `<<`):

```
cout << "Conversion: " << conversion << endl;
cout << "hash: " << hash << endl;
```

Comment: Ah.  Good to know.  That actually might come in handy at some point.  Thanks for indulging my sleep deprived stupidity.